# Use ComboBox as Query Criteria - Boolean

Tags: ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2010

I'm building a query that I'll use in a form to display a list of employees. On my form I have two comboboxes, one to filter the query by end date and one to filter by status.

The source table for the query has a Boolean field (a Yes/No field) which designates whether the employee is available or not, hence the combo to filter by status. I've run into the issue of how to use non-Boolean combo options but still have the query critera be Boolean.

I know that to use a combobox as a criteria I use this syntax: `[Forms]![Form1]![Combo4]`, but since my combo options are "In Training" and "Available" I don't know how to convert the criteria to Boolean... is this even possible?

**Example**
If my user selects "In Training" from the combo (which would be equal to `False` on the source table), my query should use `False` as the criteria for that field.

After searching Google for an hour without any luck, I'm guessing this may not be possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `IIf` expression to transform the combo's text value to Boolean.

```sql
IIf([Forms]![Form1]![Combo4] = "Available", True, False)
```

Note I assumed you want `True` when the combo's value is *"Available"* and `False` for anything else.  If the possibilities are more complex, you could use a [Switch expression](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) to assign the correct Boolean for each possible combo value ... or use a lookup table which maps between the two.